# Cannot Keep My Text Inside State By Click a Button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have my react code like this

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { TextField, Button } = MaterialUI;

const Example = props => {
  const [myText, setMyText] = useState("default text")

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("my text is :", myText)
  }, [myText])

  return (
    <div style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
      <TextField
        label="Text"
        fullWidth
        type="text"
        defaultValue={myText}
        onChange={e => {
          console.log('text: ', e.currentTarget.value);
          setMyText(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <Button onClick={() => console.log("SUBMIT TEXT :", myText)}>SUBMIT MY NAME</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.11.3/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I try to typing my text `"Hello World"`, the `useEffect` triggered and working fine, just like my input text, but after I click the `submit button`, the text back into default "default text"

Like this
[image]

How to keep my input text when I click the button?

Comment: You aren't calling `setMyText`, you're calling `setText`, which isn't in your code at all. Also, you probably want `value={myText}`, not `defaultValue={...}`.

Comment: Yes, bit wrong on my code, i update my code

Comment: when i use `value={myText}` my text field doesn't update when typing, so that I use `defaultValue={...}`

Comment: What is `<TextField>`? This should work fine with a regular `<input value={myText} onChange={e => setMyText(e.target.value)} />`.

Comment: @AKX: My company is committed to `material-ui`, so that my code using `<TextFiled>`

Comment: I just created a stack snippet and it does not reproduce the problem you describe. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Button, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";

const Example = (props) => {
  const [myText, setMyText] = React.useState("");
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("default text");
  
  return (
    <div style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <h1> {value} </h1>
      <TextField placeholder="Default" label="Enter Name" type="text" defaultValue={myText}
                 onChange={(e) => {setMyText(e.target.value)}}/>
      <br/>
      <Button style={{ marginTop: "20px" }} variant="contained" color="primary"
              onClick={() => setValue(myText)}>
        SUBMIT MY NAME
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score -1):

---

I think when you click on your button that you have imported from material, the type of button is submit so it will refresh your page and the state goes back to default.

you can test this by adding an useEffect method on component load.

```
useEffect(()=> console.log('page was refreshed') , [])
```